# Spring getAnnotation is not resolving property file read

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

Config:

```
for (Method m : objClz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (m.isAnnotationPresent(CountryEnabled.class)) {
                    GetMapping annotation1 = m.getAnnotation(GetMapping.class);
                    log.info("{}",annotation1.value());
                }
            }
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("${bean.get.endpoint}")
    public ResponseEntity getGreeting(@PathVariable String version){
        return versionController.findVersionHandler("${bean.get.endpoint}", version, HttpMethod.GET);
    }
```

Props File:

```
server.port=8081

bean.get.endpoint=/{version}/greeting
bean.get.endpoint.message=/{version}/greeting/{message}
bean.get.endpoint.message.secondmessage=/{version}/greeting/{message}/{secondmessage}
bean.post.endpoint.message=/{version}/greeting
```

Log from Config file:

```
2020-08-04 22:18:57.492  INFO 21096 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.b.a.country.CountryEnabledConfig     : [${bean.get.endpoint}]
```

It seems to be reading, **[${bean.get.endpoint}]** and not the actual value `/{version}/greeting`, is there a way to resolve it?

Comment: No as that is the value as present on the annotation.

Comment: Noted. Is there a way to extract that value from properties file?

Comment: That is what the environment can be used for or the ExpressionResolver. But rather than providing a solution what is it you are attempting to achieve?